# Searching Ruby Arrays with Regex expressions

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays

Hi I have small ruby function that splits out a Ruby array as follows:-

```
def rearrange arr,from,to
  sidx = arr.index from
  eidx = arr.index to
  arr[sidx] = arr[sidx+1..eidx]
end

arr= ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Cyan", "Magenta", "Orange", "Purple", "Pink",    "White", "Black"]
start = "Yellow"
stop = "Orange"

rearrange arr,start,stop
puts arr.inspect
#=> ["Red", "Green", "Blue", ["Cyan", "Magenta", "Orange"], "Cyan", "Magenta", "Orange", "Purple", "Pink", "White", "Black"]
```

I need use use a regex expression in my start and stop searches e.g.

Start = "/Yell/"

Stop = "/Ora/"

Is there an easy way yo do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 20):

Of course, method [`index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-index) can receive a block, so that you could do

```
sidx = arr.index{|e| e =~ from }
```

You can even check out nice Ruby's 'case equality' operator and easily cover both strings and regexes as arguments:

```
sidx = arr.index{|e| from === e} # watch out: this is not the same as 'e === from'
```

Then, if you pass a regex as `from`, it will perform regex match, and if you pass a `String`, it would look for exact string.

Comment: Superb! Very nice. Works perfectly. Thanks for the feedback.