# Delete specific element in array

Tags: ruby

I want to have the code to overwrite existing names when the score is higher than the current in the file.

The file looks like the following: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuQwp.png
This is the code:

```
def highscore(name,score)
  a = File.new("highscore.txt", "w")
  if @Bestenliste.include?("#{name}")
    x =  @Bestenliste.index("#{name}")
    @Bestenliste.delete_at(x)
  end
  @Bestenliste = @Bestenliste +  [name.to_s + "," + score.to_s]
  a.puts @Bestenliste
  a.close
end
```

Problem is, that the name and the points in the array are not seperate, and if i want to change that I need to change my whole program. Can I somehow use wildcards or something like that on the name, and also compare the score at the same time ?

I want to overwrite a specific name when it already exists and the score is higher

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the sample input? What is the desired output?

Comment: What the current output is would also be good to know. If I'm reading the code right, I think that the `include` and related statements aren't working because you're searching only by `name` and not by `name.to_s+","+score.to_s`. But it's hard to answer without really knowing what you're trying to get as a result.

Comment: The program should overwrite the names when it already exists and the score is higher, but it does not work because the name and the score in the array is not splitted. The array looks like this: `["nico,6\n","henrik,9\n","luis,2\n"]` The newlines are there because of the array being loaded from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to use a regex to search through your array and replace a specific index if found? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385572/searching-ruby-arrays-with-regex-expressions) post, about using regex to search through an array. I think you should be able to make use Mladen Jablanović's answer there. You can read up on how to use Ruby String's =~ regex matcher [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-3D-7E).

I *think* that you could accomplish it via

```
x = @Bestenliste.index{|e| e =~ /#{Regexp.quote(name)}.*/ }
unless x.nil?
  @Bestenliste.delete_at(x)
end
@Bestenliste = @Bestenliste +  [name.to_s + "," + score.to_s]
```

I used [this](http://rubular.com/r/O9fBN0iACM) to create and test the regex, and [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150095/interpolating-a-string-into-a-regex) for the string interpolation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, after I trief it the first time it just wrote the score in the empty highscore.txt. After trying it the second time it said `ln 38: in '*': wrong number of arguments`thats the line: `x = @Bestenliste.index{|e| e =~ /#{Regexp.quote(name).*}/ }`

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake in my regex! I put in the interpolation after I tested it. The `.*` needs to be on the outside of the }, so it should look like `/#{Regexp.quote(name)}.*/`. I'll edit my answer to reflect that as well.

Comment: Okay, now it says `35: in 'highscore': undefined method 'delete_at' for nil:NilClass` Did I broke the array now ?

Comment: Well, did you just copy paste my code? Because I think the problem is I made a typo. You can see I accidentally wrote `Bentenliste.delete_at` instead of `Bestenliste.delete_at` inside the unless statement. So Ruby's trying to access the array `Bentenliste` which, as the error code suggests, is `nil`. Fixing the typo should resolve that.

Comment: Error messages can be amazingly helpful if you take the time to read them! They really aren't as difficult to understand as they might first seem.

Comment: Yeah I know, most of my classmates don't even read them. But I thought I did something wrong with the regexp or something so I asked.

Comment: No, this time it was my fault. But I used your error message to see what was wrong. It's pretty straightforward. `undefined method 'delete_at' for nil:NilClass` is what it says on the tin. We tried to call a method which doesn't exist. That method was delete_at and we tried to call it on a nil object. From there, just look at any time you use delete_at and see why the object you're calling it on might be nil.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your program will be more efficient if you move the data to a hash instead of an array.

```
array.each {|set| set.split(",")}
array=array.to_h
```

Then you can easily just compare values and replace.

```
if num > array[name]
  array[name]=num
end
```

The alternative as far as I am aware would be for you to split the value when you are comparing. I don't actually see any comparison in your program. Something like

```
@Bestenlite.split(",")
  if @Bestenliste[0]==name
    if @Bestenliste[1].to_i<score
```

something like that, but that is going to heavily complicate your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, to be honest I never used a hash before so I just used a array for like everything. I should read a bit so I can do that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Once you get them they are super helpful. Good luck. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-to_h